# iOS - UILabel variable becoming (null)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit

I have searched high and low for an answer to my predicament and I believe it is due to my difficulty in adapting to ARC - I am hoping to deploy my app on iOS5 and am currently testing it in on a beta4 3GS.

When the viewController is loaded (viewDidLoad:) my app alloc init's a UILabel and customises it to add it to the top of the screen:

```
UIView *navHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44)];
self.artistLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 280, 15)];
artistLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
artistLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
artistLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
artistLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[navHeaderView addSubview:artistLabel];

self.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = navHeaderView;
```

Okay, this works fine and fills in the relevant detail by accessing a updateTrack method:

```
- (void)updateTrack 
{
    _player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
    _item = [_player nowPlayingItem];

    self._artistString = [_item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

    self.artistLabel.text = self._artistString;
}
```

This method is called when the music playing is changed using NSNotifications. However the artistString UILabel is now (null). I cannot see why the property has been released - it is set a nonatomic, strong property in the header file and synthesized at the top of the .m file.

Maybe I should also add that a nonatomic, strong property I have assigned to an IBOutlet of UIImageView also goes (null) once the app has successfully loaded, displayed the album art once (i.e. this is not added as a subview).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: This may not be related to iOS5, so I'm commenting. Seeing the property declarations would help. I suspect the valueForProperty call is returning nil. On a separate note, self._artistString just reads wrong (shouldn't be an underscore) and I would expect that self.artistLabel = [[UILabel alloc] ... is over retaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my issue was not the ARC on the variables I was using. Instead it was the notifications setup in the App Delegate that were not communicating correctly with the IBOutlets / ViewController's UILabels. Sorry to be a pain everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with being a beta iOS.

In your header are you defining the `UILabel` as well as using `@property` / `@synthesize`?

Also, remove the `self.` from the label.

Answer (score -1):

iOS5 is still under NDA.  If you are a registered developer, please ask this question in the beta Apple forums.

Comment: Hello. I have asked however to no avail. Appreciate it is still under NDA but maybe my error isn't an iOS5 specific issue, I'm just assuming.

Comment: Hi Ben, I did not mean that to sound rude at all, but most developers are very mindful of NDA's, especially when they come from Apple.  Even if the issue isn't specific to iOS5, it is still an iOS5 question which can't legally be answered here.  May I suggest rewriting in iOS4 with standard memory management and seeing if it works?  That way you can isolate the OS discrepancy, and perhaps get a useful response here.

Comment: Or post a link here to the Apple developer forum topic you made so visitors to this question can answer there, if they do not feel comfortable breaking NDAs.

Comment: Thanks folks. I began a iOS4 rewrite then realised it was an issue with the NSNotificationCenter code. The notifications were being setup in the App Delegate calling methods within the main View Controller. However methods within the View Controllers couldn't connect with the variables.

Comment: I should add thank you for your time, a silly mistake I wont make again!